# Which digital signature algorithm to choose for multi-platform use?

Tags: java, security, sign

I have a Java written web service verifying digitally signed requests via public keys. Clients could be written in different languages, PHP for example. So I want to choose an key/signing algorithm wisely... For example, official Java [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/index.html) on signing offers `DSA` keys and `SHA1withDSA` signature but there are some [complains](http://mark.koli.ch/2009/03/howto-using-sha1withrsa-signing-in-php.html) for using the latter with PHP.

Which signing algorithm could I choose?

1. Commonly accepted as being strong enough
2. Having good support in standard Java at Linux
3. Having good support at other recognized programming platforms

Comment: There's actually not much choice here :) and RSA is the only viable alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSA.  Java has a ton of libraries for it and it is the most widely used.  Shouldn't use SHA1 either.

Comment: Thank you for the both points! Now `SHA512withRSA` provided by `SunRsaSign` looks suitable for me.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to really confirm that you're doing it in a way supported by those platforms is to verify it yourself. Even if you use something that should work in theory there may be a difference in their implementations that makes it not work.

You could study how Google and Facebook do theirs. You can read the code in the libraries that people use to communicate with those services using different platforms to get an idea of how you want to implement yours.